# Lollipop plays call notification ringtone instead of notification ringtone when a text is received

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, ringtone

**Device: Motorola Moto G4 Plus**

First of all, I set a custom ringtone for the calls. That works as intended. Now the issue is that custom ringtone is played whenever I receive a text as well. I expect the notification ringtone to be played whenever a text is received.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the `Messenger` app has its own notification setting. Google has an article where to access the setting(s).

https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6080337?hl=en